# (linkedin) IN.User.Authorize callback never fired

Tags: linkedin-api

Our application is using LinkedIn JavaScript SDK to login and then share post to LinkedIn, but recently it stopped working.

After login, call back is not happening and hence not able to proceed with other steps like LinkedIn Share.

I saw one post where it was mentioned, the issue came in past and it has reoccurred.

the link for the issue mentioned last time: [IN.User.Authorize callback never fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53323724/in-user-authorize-callback-never-fired)